# How to turn off Background Music using a Toggle Switch in Xcode using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am playing background music in my app from the App delegate once the app launches. Now, In my 2nd V.C. I have set up a toggle switch to turn om/off the background music. But, whenever I am running the follwing code, my app is crashing giving me this error:-

```
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
```

Could anyone please let me know how can I implement the following task in my V.C. Would appreciate your help! Thanks:)

```
**App Delegate**

let vc = SecondViewController()

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    
    vc.playMusic()
    
    return true
}

**Second View Controller**

import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var musicToggleSwitch: UISwitch!

var music: AVAudioPlayer!

let vc_1 = ViewController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  
    self.musicToggleSwitch.setOn(UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "musicToggleState"), animated: true)
    
   }

@IBAction func musicToggleSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    
    if (musicToggleSwitch.isOn == true) {
        
        if (music.isPlaying == false) {
            
            music.play()
            
        }
        
    }
    else {
        
        if (music.isPlaying == true) {
            
            music.stop()
            
        }
        
    }
    
    UserDefaults.standard.set(sender.isOn, forKey: "musicToggleState")

}

func playMusic() {
    
    if let musicURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Music", withExtension: "mp3") {
        if let audioPlayer = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: musicURL) {
            music = audioPlayer
            music.numberOfLoops = -1
            music.play()
        }
    }
    
}
```

}

Comment: can you write NSLog to see where get the nil value ?

Comment: @zeytin Thanks for your reply! I am get an error on the this line:if (music.isPlaying == true) {

Comment: var music: AVAudioPlayer?  can you do it optional like this ?

Comment: @zeytin I tried that, but now the app is not crashing but, the music is still not stopping after I toggle the switch

Comment: Can you check if the musicURL is valid? I assume creating the music player fails in `playMusic()` and when you toggle the switch it tries to access `music` which is nil

Comment: @AlexGoergisn I am able to run the background music from the app delegate method when the app launches. But, not from the 2nd V.C. by toggling the switch. So, the musicURL is valid

Comment: On which line do you get your error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your issues.

If it still doesn't play, add some breakpoints in the creation block of the music variable to see what goes wrong.

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var musicToggleSwitch: UISwitch!
    
    var music: AVAudioPlayer? = {
        guard let musicURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Music", withExtension: "mp3") else {
            return nil
        }
        
        let audioPlayer = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: musicURL)
        audioPlayer?.numberOfLoops = -1
        return audioPlayer
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.musicToggleSwitch.setOn(UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "musicToggleState"), animated: true)
    }
    
    @IBAction func musicToggleSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        guard let music = music, sender.isOn != music.isPlaying else {
            return
        }
        
        if sender.isOn {
            music.play()
        } else {
            music.stop()
        }
        
        UserDefaults.standard.set(sender.isOn, forKey: "musicToggleState")
    }
    
    func playMusic() {
        music?.play()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
let vc = SecondViewController()
```

That is not the same SecondViewController that you see in your interface. So `playMusic` is called on the wrong view controller, and on the view controller you can see `music` remains `nil` and you crash.

Comment: Please read http://www.programmingios.net/dont-make-a-new-instance-by-mistake/

Comment: Indeed, because you hold this second SecondViewController alive, invisible, in the app delegate. But that is not the SecondViewController whose button you see and tap, where the crash is. One must appreciate the difference between classes and instances that is fundamental to object oriented programming. You have two SecondViewController instances, and two `music` players, and one of them is nil, for its `playMusic` was never called. And all the downvotes in the world will not falsify my words, which are simple truth.